# Title label is missing in Image Properties - Sitecore Media Image

Tags: media-library

In my application when editing, image properties from a rich text editor the label is missing for "Title". (Ref. Image)

[image]

Anybody having an idea of where to configure the label?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see the same issue in my project. We have Sitecore 8.2 (Update 5). I have raised it with the Sitecore support team. I'll let you know their response. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @navneetkeshav below answer (Marek Musielak) is working fine. Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like translation is missing in `RadEditor.Dialogs.resx` file.

In order to add it:

1. Find your web app root on the
2. Navigate to `sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\Localization` folder
3. Open `RadEditor.Dialogs.resx` file
4. Search for `Common_ImageAltText` string. You should find:

```
<data name="Common_ImageAltText" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Alt Text</value>
</data>
```

5. Add new data node below the `<data name="Common_ImageAltText"`:

```
<data name="Common_ImageTitleText" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Title Text You Like</value>
</data>
```

6. Clear browser cache and refresh the window.

Your translation should be there:

[image]

Comment: Great. Usually people mark answer as correct if it works for them ;)

Comment: Hi @Marek Musielak, Since I am new to this community so could not able to vote (System is not accepting my vote). That is why I mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I didn't mean voting. I meant accepting answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers